# Refer to element ID set dynamically through Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am setting the ID of an element, say a button, dynamically. An example is given below (the code may have syntactic errors, I am merely trying to explain my problem).

```
function myFunc(){
    var counter = 0;
    return function(){
        counter += 1;
        var rowContent = '<div>';
        rowContent += '<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="button"' + counter + '></button>';
        rowContent += '</div>';
        $('#someElement').append(rowContent);
    };
}
```

Now I want to associate a click event with the button. I need to mention the ID element when associating the event with the button (e.g. $('#myID')). But since the ID is being set dynamically, I do not know for sure what the ID may be. Could someone tell me how I could refer to the dynamically-set ID of the element when associating an event with it? Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Since you don't know the ID, why not use the class? If not, how about using `.on()`'s event delegation syntax?

Comment: You don't need to use ID. `rowContent` contains the only button, so just select the 1st button in `rowContent`: `rowContent.find('button').on(...)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Delegate the event](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) to the parent element `rowContent`.

```
$('#someElement').append(rowContent);
$('button', rowContent).on('click', function(e) {
    // button element in the 'rowContent' context
}
```

Delegating it to `#someElement` will also work, unless you'll be putting multiple buttons with *different* click handlers inside of there.

Comment: Ok, so that way, suppose there are 5 rows, and any button in one of the rows (each having one button) is clicked, the event will execute for elements in that specific row only?

Comment: Should do, yes. However, if you're wanting the same, or similar, click event to happen for every button, you should delegate it *once* to a common ancestor element and use `this` in your event handler to indicate the button that was actually clicked.

Comment: Thank you, I got what you mean. I'll do it now.

Answer (score 2):

You should better be using event delegation in such case:

```
$('#someElement').on('click','[id^=button]',function(){
  //do stuff 
});
```

Comment: Thank you also for the help!

Comment: @user3033194: glad it helps :)

Answer (score 0):

You can easily define your own custom attribute and select it with this attribute as:

```
rowContent += '<button type="button" mybtn="" class="btn btn-default" id="button"' + counter + '></button>';
```

and here is the selector:

```
$("div[mybtn]")
```